# Print the points table of a cricket match using Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve this question using the join and nested queries. However I am facing issue while printing the final result as there are two rows which are not correctly printed. I am posting below question and the relevant details.

Sql query to fetch the Team name, total number of matches Played by  each team, no of match won by the team and no of match lost by the team .

Below is Schema and sample data:

```sql
create table cricket(
    Match_no int,
    Team_a  varchar(20),
    Team_b  varchar(20),
    Winner  varchar(20)
);

Insert into cricket (Match_no,Team_a,Team_b,Winner) values 
(1,'westindies','srilanka'  ,'westindies'), 
(2  ,'india ','srilanka'    ,'india'),
(3  ,'australia'    ,'srilanka' ,'australia'),
(4  ,'westindies'   ,'srilanka',    'srilanka'),
(5  ,'australia'    ,'india'    ,'australia'),
(6, 'westindies'    ,'srilanka' ,'westindies'),
(7  ,'india'    ,'westindies'   ,'westindies'),
(8  ,'westindies'   ,'australia',   'australia'),
(9  ,'westindies',  'india','india'),
(10,'australia',    'westindies',   'westindies'),
(11 ,'westindies'   ,'srilanka' ,'westindies'),
(12 ,'india'    ,'australia',   'india'),
(13,    'srilanka'  ,'newzealand',  'srilanka'),
(14 ,'newzealand'   ,'india',   'india')
```

I am using below query, but the matches won and lost is  not correct for SriLanka and Newzeland in my output.

```sql
    select team.t as Teamname,count(1)as  Played ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN team.t = c.Winner THEN 1 ELSE 0 end ) as WON,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN team.t <> c.Winner THEN 1 ELSE 0 end ) ) as Lost
    from 
    (select  distinct Team_a as t from cricket where Team_a in (
    select Team_b as t from cricket)) team
    join cricket c on team.t in (c.Team_a,c.Team_b)
    group by team.t order by 2 desc;
```

My output:

```
Teamname    Played  WON Lost
westindies    8      5   3
srilanka      7      2   5
india         6      4   2
australia     5      3   2
newzealand  2        0   2
```

Expected outcome:

```
Team_name   No_of_matches_played      Matches_won   Matches_lost
westindies           8                   5          3
india                6                   4          2
australia            5                   3          2
srilanka             7                   1          6
newzealand           2                   1          1
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  How are ties handled?

Comment: Could you explain how your output is incorrect for Sri Lanka and New Zealand? It looks correct to me, while the expected output for those 2 teams seems wrong.

Comment: @ShreyasSabnis yes , I realize my mistake. I was referring the wrong data set to compare my output.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot an aggregate.  The idea is:

```
select team, count(*), count(*), sum(is_win),
       count(*) - sum(is_win) as num_losses
from ((select team_a as team,
              (team_a = winner) as is_win
       from cricket
      ) union all
      (select team_b as team,
              (team_b = winner) as is_win
       from cricket
      )
     ) c
group by team;
```

This assumes there are no ties.  Your question says nothing about them.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```sql
select 
    t2.team, 
    t2.played as played , 
    COALESCE (t3.won, 0) as won, 
    (t2.played - COALESCE (t3.won, 0)) as lost 
from 
(
    select sum(cnt) as played, team 
    from 
    (
        select count(1) as cnt, team_a as team 
        from cricket 
        group by team_a
        union ALL 
        select count(1) as cnt, team_b as team 
        from cricket 
        group by team_b
    ) t1
group by team
) t2
left join 
(
    select count(1) as won, winner 
    from cricket group by winner
) t3
on t2.team = t3.winner
order by t3.won desc;
```